# How can I add these fields up in django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

The form has been submitted and I did a request.POST to get the values, now I want to put them into a table and add them up.

View:

```
inst = TableRound_1.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
scoring = TableScore.objects.create(couple_r1 = inst, number = number, judge = judge, timing = timing, technique = technique, connection = connection, presentation = presentation, difficulty = difficulty, choreo = choreo )
inst.score = scoring.aggregate(Sum[timing, technique, connection, presentation, difficulty, choreo])
inst.save()
```

Comment: As the fields are coming from `POST` why don't you use those for summation to be stored in `inst.score` e.g. `inst.score = sum([timing, technique, connection, presentation, difficulty, choreo])`? Note `sum` here is python built in function.

Comment: What error are you getting?